# What O.T passages do premillenialists believe to be about the Millennial Kingdom?

Tags: old-testament, eschatology, word-of-faith, premillennialism

What passages do premilleialists, that is, those who believe the "1000 year reign of Christ to be a literal event to occur only after the second coming of Christ, find in the Old testament that they believe to be prophesying about the Millennial Kingdom?

Comment: @Caleb - "Your definition of "mainstream Christianity" doesn't help at all ... Jehovah Witnesses and Mormons might both fit that umbrella" - My definition of the main-stream Christianity excludes Jehovah Witnesses and Mormons from taking part in answering my question in the first place.

Comment: @brilliant It only excludes them in your head: by the definitions in their head it does not. I can show you videos of LDS church leaders praying in Jesus name just as you describe. That isn't a good metric of mainstream that other people can understand and apply. They will understand it differently than you do.

Comment: @Caleb "I can show you videos of LDS church leaders praying in Jesus name just as you describe"  - You don't need to. I know how they pray all too well. Praying to God, addressing Him by name "Jesus" is absolutely different from praying to God and adding "we are praying in the name of Your Son Jesus Christ" in the end of the prayer. I thought I spelled that out clearly enough in my definition. It is just as different as "Caleb, I want to tell you this and this ... " is different from saying to someone "I am telling you this and this in the name of that Caleb".

Comment: Who on earth deleted my comment with definition of main-stream Christianity? And why was it omitted from my question? I am not at all interested in knowing the answer from those who out of principle don't pray to Jesus.

Comment: It's quite an unnecessary distinction for this question and as I said confusing and not likely to actually communicate what you wanted. On the other hand premillenialists are a subset of mainstream Christianity, so this narrower scope will work better and still only include people that fit your definition.

Comment: @Caleb - "It's quite an unnecessary distinction for this question" - Caleb, it's unnecessary in your head, but to me it's more than unnecessary. I simply don't want to waste my time on reading stuff from some people who are not born of God. I mean I wouldn't mind doing it at other time, but at the moment I need some quick answer from a brother in Christ, not just from someone who calls himself a Christian. That's why I said in my question earlier that I want a main-stream perspective. BTW, the definition to "main-stream" was not in question, it was my answer in a comment to a question about it

Comment: No matter what you write or what your definition of, this site is not a place where you can get any assurance that what comes back is from a born again brother. This is an internet site run by a secular company with a general scope of a professed religion. Even if you had a much narrower scope on your question, the answers still may be written by non Christians who just happen to know about the doctrines in question. There is nothing you can do about that. If that doesn't suit you this isn't the place for you.

Comment: On the other hand if you get answers that are out of scope doctrinally we have ways of cleaning them up. The current scope on this question precludes doctrine of groups that don't believe in a Jesus second coming from being valid answers.

Comment: @Caleb - "This is an internet site run by a secular company with a general scope of a ..." - Do you really think that you need to start singing this same old song to me almost each time when I ask a new question?! I know what kind of site this one is. Specifying that I want to hear from a "main-stream" is a small attempt to narrow down to (not to secure) the scope that I am trying to target here - there is nothing wrong in making such an attempt and I have all rights to do it. BTW, if you really have a video with JW or LDS addressing Jesus in prayer, then, please, send a link to me.

Answer (score 2):

I am Word of Faith we are pretribulational dispensational premillennialism. We believe Zechariah 14 and Ezekiel 43-48 are all used to describe the millennium kingdom of Christ on the earth. Zechariah 14 describes the return of Christ with His saints from a governmental standpoint. Gill's Exposition of the Entire Bible Zechariah 14:5 holds the idea the millennial reign is being discussed throughout this chapter. Ezekiel 43-48 largely focuses on the Glory of God returning to Israel and the return of their priesthood during the millennial reign. Its difficult to point to one reliable source which states this but many independent sources say as much on google and I know it is what is taught by [Billye Brim](http://www.billyebrim.org/) in her School of Eschatology on Ezekiel which is no longer available for purchase. While Rev 20 is on the same topic since it is describing a different aspect of the return of Christ it doesn't directly correlate to either chapters from the Old Testament.

> Zec 14:5  And ye shall flee to the valley of the mountains; for the valley of the mountains shall reach unto Azal: yea, ye shall flee, like as ye fled from before the earthquake in the days of Uzziah king of Judah: and the LORD my God shall come, and all the saints with thee.

[Gill's Exposition of the Entire Bible Zechariah 14:5](http://biblehub.com/zechariah/14-5.htm)

> and the Lord my God shall come; the Lord Jesus Christ, who is truly God, and the God of his people; and who will appear to be so at his second coming, which is here meant, by raising the dead, gathering all nations before him, and separating them; by bringing to light all secret and hidden things; judging the whole world, and executing the sentence on them; and particularly by taking his own people to himself:
>
> and all the saints with thee: the Targum, and the Septuagint, Syriac, and Arabic versions, read, "with him"; meaning either the holy angels; so Aben Ezra, Kimchi, and Ben Melech; who will attend him partly for the glory of his majesty, and partly for terror to the wicked, and also for service; or rather glorified saints, the spirits of just men made perfect, whom Christ will bring with him to be united to their bodies, which will now be raised, and to be with him in the new heavens and new earth, which will now be formed, and to be presented to him, and dwell with him, during the thousand years.

and

> Eze 44:3  It is for the prince; the prince, he shall sit in it to eat bread before the LORD; he shall enter by the way of the porch of that gate, and shall go out by the way of the same.